# How to merge two sorted lists without repeatedly calling insert function

Tags: java

I have already gotten the data from a file into a list with just integers but cannot figure out how to merge with out for loops calling to insertAt. heres the code i have so far

```
 public Davies_OrderedArrayList(Davies_OrderedArrayList list2){
  Davies_OrderedArrayList list3 =new Davies_OrderedArrayList();
  int j=0;
  while(j<this.length){
   list3.insert(j);
   j++;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `addAll()` method on your ArrayList.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)